# Issue dividing one dataframe by another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have rewritten this question several times now as I thought I had solved the issue, however it appears not. I am currently trying to loop through columns of df1 and df2, dividing one column by the other to populate columns of a new df3 but I am having the issue that that all my cells are NaN.

My code for the loop is as follows:

```
#Divide One by the Other. Set up for loop
i = 0
for country in df3.columns:    
    df3[country] = df1.iloc[:, [i]].div(df2.iloc[:, [i]])
    i += 1
```

The resulting df3 is a matrix full of NaNs only.

My df1 is of the structure:

[image]

And my df2 of the structure:

[image]

And I am creating my df3 as:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index = df1.index, columns=tickers.index)
```

Which looks like (before population):

[image]

The only potential issue is the multi index in df3 perhaps? Struggling to see why they don't divide through.

Comment: Did you try this? `df3[:] = df1.values / df2.values` The problem is the misaligned index.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I concur. That should work

Comment: @piRSquared Just noticed... df1 has 31 columns, df2 has 27, and df3 has 31 again. I'm not sure where OP hopes to get the remainder of those missing cols from.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ could find the min col length np.min([d.shape[0] for d in [df1, df2, df3]])

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will look into the number of columns as they should be the same.

On a related note, is there a reason why df1.iloc[:, [i]].div(df1.iloc[:, [i]]) gives NaNs on certain rows? (i.e. the same dataframe divided by itself).

Answer (score 6):

The reason why your current approach does not work is because you're dividing `pd.Series` objects. `pandas` automatically tries to align the indices when dividing. Here's an example.

```
df1

5    0
4    1
3    2
2    3
1    4
dtype: int64

df2

5    0
6    1
7    2
8    3
9    4
dtype: int64

df1 / df2    # you'd expect all 1's in each row, but...

1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

Ensure that you have the same number of rows and columns in `df1` and `df2`, and then this should becomes easy if you divide the `np.array` counterparts of the dataframes.

```
v = df1.values / df2.values
df3 = pd.DataFrame(v, index=df1.index, columns=tickers.index)
```

Comment: Thanks coldspeed. Without sounding lazy, as I have been trying to get my head around this today, is there a type of 'select from' type statement that can be run between two or more dataframes?

e.g. Select from df1 and df2 where indices are the same

Comment: @CuriousStudent Well, I think you're looking for a merge. Alternatively, you could just do `idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)` and then use `idx` to index both dataframes. Anyway, these are different questions, so you should ask a new question.

Comment: @CuriousStudent Anyway, if this helped, don't forget to vote on the answer and accept if you're satisfied. Thanks

Comment: The thing I don't get here is that my indices are aligned at least for some rows, which should give a value, but it doesn't.

Comment: @CuriousStudent When I say indices.... I mean the index as well as the columns. Both have to align. It’s pretty simple once you figure out what’s going on.

Comment: @CuriousStudent A reminder, if your question was addressed, please accept the answer. Thank you.